# Rendering g-code coordinates in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering, g-code

I need to develop a g-code visualizer that will build lines according to g-code.
The task is quite simple. I need that in the WPF window, in the 3d component all the lines are displayed according to g-code. It should be possible to increase/decrease the size, rotate the camera.
There are no problems with the g-code processing module. I just need to decide which graphics engine to use for rendering.
I faced such a task for the first time.

At the moment it seems to me that unity3d is suitable for this task. I integrate unity app in the WPF window. It use "-parentHWND" parameter and integrated in wpf window.
Perhaps I am mistaken and there are simpler solutions. If so, then please suggest these solutions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj0Um.jpg)

Comment: Are you asking how to display 3d in WPF? There is `Viewport3D`, see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview).

Comment: No. I need to choose a graphical engine for my task.

Comment: You could try HelixToolkit  [link](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit)